# gcovr compare two reports

Tags: c++, unit-testing, code-coverage, gcovr

I find it really difficult when refactoring huge codebase, changing tests etc. to find on my code coverage report what lines I'm no longer covering.

Is there any tool/way to get diff from two reports?

Comment: You are asking for recommendations for tools which is not desired on StackOverflow.

Comment: If you want to see diff, use some tool like Meld.

Answer (score 1):

Gcovr currently has no support for showing coverage changes. This gives you roughly the following two options:

- You can use [gcovr's JSON output](https://gcovr.com/en/stable/output/json.html#json-output) and write your own script to compare the results from multiple different runs.
- You can use a different tool. For example, [Henry Cox has created a fork of the `lcov` tool](https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov/pull/86) with interesting support for differential coverage. Many third party tools can show coverage changes, for example the Codecov.io service. If you're running some CI system, there might already be a feature of plugin to highlight coverage changes.

As an example of a script to process gcovr's JSON output, the following would alert you of lines that lost coverage:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, json

def main(baseline_json: str, alternative_json: str):
  baseline = load_covered_lines(baseline_json)
  alternative = load_covered_lines(alternative_json)

  found_any_differences = False

  # compare covered lines for each source file
  for filename in sorted(baseline):
    difference = baseline[filename] - alternative[filename]

    if not difference:
      print(f"info: {filename}: ok")
      continue

    found_any_differences = True
    for lineno in sorted(difference):
      print(f"error: {filename}: {lineno}: not covered in {alternative_json}")

  if found_any_differences:
    sys.exit(1)


def load_covered_lines(gcovr_json_file: str) -> dict[str, set[int]]:
  # JSON format is documented at
  # <https://gcovr.com/en/stable/output/json.html#json-format-reference>

  with open(gcovr_json_file) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

  # The JSON format may change between versions
  assert data["gcovr/format_version"] == "0.3"

  covered_lines = dict()
  for filecov in data["files"]:
    covered_lines[filecov["file"]] = set(
      linecov["line_number"]
      for linecov in filecov["lines"]
      if linecov["count"] != 0 and not linecov["gcovr/noncode"]
    )

  return covered_lines


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Example usage:

```bash
./old-configuration
gcovr --json baseline.json

find . -name '*.gcda' -exec rm {} +  # delete old coverage data

./new-configuration
gcovr --json alternative.json

python3 diffcov.py baseline.json alternative.json
```

Example output:

```
error: changed.c: 2: not covered in alternative.json
info: same.c: ok
```

You could create a similar script that also opens the original source files to create an annotated report with all coverage changes, similar to the textual reports generated by `gcov`.